# iMacros VBScript Error 800A000D Type Mismatch

Tags: sql, vbscript, imacros

I'm getting an error on a vb script that connects my report database to an iMacros macro for entry to a web form. It is basically the same code as the example from their site (Database-2-Web Script), just with some extra fields. The data types are all varchar. Error message below:

```
 Script: C:\users\me\path\file.vbs 
 Line: 70 
 Char: 4 
 Error: Type mismatch: 'iimSet' 
 Code: 800A000D 
 Source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error
```

Line 70, which is:

```
 iret = iim1.iimSet("RiskStatusReason", rs.fields(48))
```

I can't see what makes that line special. It is the same as the others, so why the error here? Any VB pros have answers to this? I am brand new to VBS.

Full code below (I added the cheerleading message):

```
Option Explicit
dim rs, iim1, sql
dim myname, mypath, connstring
dim iret


dim message 
message = "This script reads data from a SQL Server database and submits this information to a web form."
message = message + " It reads from the database <database> and uses the macro <wsh-submit-2-web>." + vbCrLf + VbCrLf 
message = message + "Tip: This script has the same function as <file-2-web-method2.vbs> but reads the data from a database instead of a text file." + vbCrLf + VbCrLf
message = message + "Tip: You're incredible, go get 'em tiger."

MsgBox (message)

'Note for x64 users: You must start the VBS script in 32bit mode (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wscript.exe) for the Microsoft ODBC Driver to work
'Please see the note about VBS scripts on http://wiki.imacros.net/x64 for more details 

' find current folder
myname = WScript.ScriptFullName
mypath = Left(myname, InstrRev(myname, "\"))


' open ACCESS database
set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

'connstring = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=" & mypath & "IIM-TEST-SUBMIT.MDB"

'NOTE: To open an SQL database instead of an ACCESS database please use:
'
connstring = "driver={SQL Server};server=server\server1;uid=user;pwd=password;database=database"
'
    rs.Open (connstring)

    ' use SQL to select information
    sql = "select * from _Temp"
    set rs = rs.Execute(sql)

    set iim1= CreateObject ("imacros")
    iret = iim1.iimOpen("")
    iret = iim1.iimDisplay("Submitting Data from SQL Server")

    do until rs.eof
       'Set the variable
       iret = iim1.iimSet("AccountingName", rs.fields(9))
       iret = iim1.iimSet("ReportFileDate", rs.fields(8))
       iret = iim1.iimSet("LastWeekStatus", rs.fields(31))
       iret = iim1.iimSet("CurrentStatus", rs.fields(32))
       iret = iim1.iimSet("TrendingStatus", rs.fields(33))
       iret = iim1.iimSet("Headline", rs.fields(28))
       iret = iim1.iimSet("CostStatus", rs.fields(34))
       iret = iim1.iimSet("CostStatusReason", rs.fields(43))
       iret = iim1.iimSet("ScheduleStatus", rs.fields(35))
       iret = iim1.iimSet("ScheduleStatusReason", rs.fields(44))
       iret = iim1.iimSet("ScopeStatus", rs.fields(36))
       iret = iim1.iimSet("ScopeStatusReason", rs.fields(45))
       iret = iim1.iimSet("TMStatus", rs.fields(37))
       iret = iim1.iimSet("TMStatusReason", rs.fields(46))
       iret = iim1.iimSet("ResourceStatus", rs.fields(38))
       iret = iim1.iimSet("ResourceStatusReason", rs.fields(47))
       iret = iim1.iimSet("RiskStatus", rs.fields(39))
       iret = iim1.iimSet("RiskStatusReason", rs.fields(48))
       iret = iim1.iimSet("BenefitsStatus", rs.fields(40))
       iret = iim1.iimSet("BenefitsStatusReason", rs.fields(49))
       iret = iim1.iimSet("QualityStatus", rs.fields(41))
       iret = iim1.iimSet("QualityStatusReason", rs.fields(50))
       iret = iim1.iimSet("Filename", rs.fields(2))

     iret = iim1.iimPlay(mypath & "Macros\_SRfromSQL.iim")
       If iret < 0 Then
            MsgBox "Error code: "+cstr(iret) + VbCrLf + "Error Text: "+iim1.iimGetErrorText()
       End If
      rs.movenext
    loop

    iret = iim1.iimDisplay("Done!")
    iret = iim1.iimClose
    WScript.Quit(iret)
```

Comment: Maybe `rs.fields(48)` could result to `NULL`, i.e. contains no valid data, or to other than string format? Suppose next [valid syntax](http://wiki.imacros.net/iimSet) `int ret_code = iimSet ( String VARNAME, String VARVALUE )`

Comment: Is the error generated for a specific row, the first row, the last row, any row? is this data binding? have you checked the type of the actual data being returned by your query against the datatype you have defined for "RiskStatusReason"?

Comment: To check subtype information use `msgbox CStr(VarType(rs.fields(48))) & VarName(rs.fields(48))`